# recursion to find the sum for fraction

Tags: java

I want to write a recursion to find the sum of fraction:
for example: 
input: 3
output: 1/1+1/2+1/3 which equal to 1.83333333....
That's what I have right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class fsd{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a = 0;
    int n = k.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        a = getSum(i);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}

public static double getSum(int i) {
    if (i > 1) {
        double curStep = 1 / (i + 1.0);
        return curStep + getSum(i - 1);
    } else if (i == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Looks ok. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's my solution and it works.....

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class fsd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a = 0;
        int n = k.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            a = getSum(i);
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    }

    public static double getSum(int i) {
        if (i > 1) {
            double curStep = 1.0 / (i);
            return curStep + getSum(i - 1);
        } else if(i == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } 
    //1+(1+1/3) + (1+1/3+1/4)
}
```